# Unity 5: Use Network Simulator, should I?

Tags: networking, unity, unity-networking

I am looking to test intelligent prioritisation of a client server game. In my scenario, two clients are connected to the server. I want one client to have a good connection to the server while the others is poor. With my test environment the server and clients are machines within a lab. Can the network simulator within the Network Manager Script do this? Can the network simulator be used on the clients or does it have to be used on the server? Can I, for my situation, have one client use it and bump up the latency or packet loss and then have the other client not use it? I couldn't find anything within Unity's Documentation about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone looking for good network simulation software go here https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/
Clumsy doesnt need installed or anything, just run it and specify your parameters. I realise it is really simple but it is what I needed. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: That right the tool I was looking for to test network gaming for my project. Thank you so much!